# Three-way comparison of CRTP-ed std::vectors

Tags: c++, comparison, c++20, crtp

In [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.12338.pdf) I've stumbled upon this obscure code (which is presented casually, like this is a totally normal C++ code):

```
struct Tree : std::vector<Tree> {};
```

Two trees are then created and compared (see [the demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/orr71rKjY)):

```
Tree tree(size_t h)
{
  Tree s;
  if (h > 0)
    s.insert(s.end(), 2, tree(h - 1));
  return s;
}

int main()
{
  size_t h = 15;
  Tree s1 = tree(h);
  Tree s2 = tree(h);
  clock_t t = clock();
  s1 < s2;
  double d = clock() - t;
  d /= CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  std::cout << d << std::endl; // 4.1s
}
```

After some thinking, I've realized this comparison seems legal and will always yield false.

The idea of the article is that since C++17 implements comparisons of vectors with [`std::lexicographical_compare`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare), which compares corresponding elements `a` and `b` in two sequences as both `a<b` and `b<a` (see "Possible implementation" section on cpppreference), the performance for deep structures like the `Tree` above will degrade quadratically on the depth. And indeed it does.

The article also says that three-way comparison does not have such a problem. But wait, that's exactly what emerged in C++20 with `operator<=>`. But here is the caveat.

This code does not compile in C++20:

```
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-snapshot/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11.0.1/../../../../include/c++/11.0.1/compare:914:35: fatal error: recursive template instantiation exceeded maximum depth of 1024
        = decltype(__detail::__synth3way(std::declval<_Tp&>(),
```

Here is my question. Is this compile error a bug in the compiler, or is this code actually ill-formed? If the code is ill-formed, is it so only for C++20 or for both C++17 and C++20? (The latter would imply that this code compiles under C++17 only by chance).

Comment: Looks like [compare_three_way](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/compare/compare_three_way) in GCC 11 is broken, it can't even compile [the example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bDk2qMI2RA6CLGco).

Comment: @rustyx No, that's correct. `compare_three_way` just has stricter requirements than simply checking for `<=>`: `three_way_comparable_with` also requires `equality_comparable`.

Comment: It’s exponential, not merely quadratic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is constraint recursion.

In C++17, `vector<T>`'s `operator<` had a precondition that `<` was defined for `T`, but libstdc++ didn't check this. Their implementation [was basically](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_vector.h#L1928-L1932):

```cpp
template <typename T>
inline bool operator<(vector<T> const& a, vector<T> const& b) {
    return lexicographical_compare(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end());
}
```

This... just works.

But in C++20, `vector<T>` instead has `operator<=>`, which has a constraint:

```cpp
template <typename T>
    // this checks either <=> or <
    requires synth_3way_comparable<T>
auto operator<=>(vector<T> const& a, vector<T> const& b) { ... }
```

The problem here is that: in order to figure out of `Tree` is three-way comparable, we have to figure out if we can call `<=>` on two `Tree`s, which finds this `operator<=>(vector<Tree>, vector<Tree>)` candidate, which is only defined if `Tree` is three-way-comparable, so we have to figure out if we can call `<=>` on two `Tree`s, which finds ...

So that... doesn't work, and can't work.

Unfortunately it's not even a question of: just adding `==` and `<=>` to `Tree`, since `vector`'s `<=>` will still be a candidate and just asking the question of whether or not it is valid explodes.

As a result, this isn't a viable strategy for implementing comparisons in C++20. You won't be able to inherit from `vector` like this. You'll have to just add it as a member.

Comment: Similar to the other answer, this explains why the current implementation of the standard library fails, but strictly speaking, this does not imply the program is ill-formed. It is not clear to me why `std::three_way_comparable_with` cannot work on `Tree` in some other stdlib implementation.

Comment: Just curious, why `operator==` on two `vector<Tree>` doesn't need such constraints as `std::equality_comparable` for the `Tree`. It seems standard treat `operator==/std::ranges::equal` slightly loose in C++20.

Comment: @Mikhail Constraint recursion is ill-formed.

Comment: @康桓瑋 `equality_comparable` also requires `!=` so that might break existing code.

Comment: Can you add a defaulted `operator<=>` to short-circuit the constraint?  (Maybe default it outside the class?  I heard someone allowed that…)

Comment: @DavisHerring Add a default or member `operator<=>` for `Tree` is not work, but we [can](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/MzhdGscxv) add a global `operator<=>` to make it compile, but this is pointless since `s1 < s2` just call the global one once.

Comment: @DavisHerring Problem is `vector`'s is a non-member, so it'd always be a candidate, and attempting to instantiate that candidate blows up.

Comment: Constraint recursion is ill-formed, but is `operator<=>` for vectors required to have a constraint? I don't see one on in the standard http://eel.is/c++draft/vector.syn

Comment: @Mikhail You have to look up what [`synth-three-way-result`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expos.only.func) means.

Answer (score 1):

This code is well-formed in C++17 and ill-formed in C++20.

Consider the following two 2-height tree:

```
struct Tree : std::vector<Tree> {};

int main() {
  Tree s1 = tree(1);
  Tree s2 = tree(1);
  s1 < s2;
}
```

In C++17, we just call the `vector`'s `operator<`:

```
bool operator<(const vector<Tree>& x, const vector<Tree>& y) { 
  return std::lexicographical_compare(x.begin(), x.end(), y.begin(), y.end()); 
}
```

which will invoke the `std::lexicographical_compare`:

```
template <class InputIt1, class InputIt2>
bool lexicographical_compare(InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1,
                             InputIt2 first2, InputIt2 last2) {
  for (; (first1 != last1) && (first2 != last2); ++first1, (void)++first2) {
    if (*first1 < *first2) return true;
    if (*first2 < *first1) return false;
  }
  return (first1 == last1) && (first2 != last2);
}
```

In first comparison `*first1 < *first2`, `*first1` is the left node of `s1`, and `*first2` is the left node of `s2`, and their type is `Tree`, so we back to compare two `Tree`s. At this time, we don't have the `operator<` for the `Tree`, so we back to call their base's `operator<` just like we first do, which is:

```
bool operator<(const vector<Tree>& x, const vector<Tree>& y) { 
  return std::lexicographical_compare(x.begin(), x.end(), y.begin(), y.end()); 
}
```

But this time, the base `vector` of the two nodes is actually empty, so in the deeper `lexicographical_compare` function, we just return false. And the second comparison `*first2 < *first1` following the same procedure.

Until now, we complete the left node comparison, then we can `++first1, (void)++first2` to continue the right node comparison.

In C++20, the `s1 < s2` rewrite as:

```
(s1 <=> s2) < 0
```

so we call the `vector`'s `operator<=>`:

```
auto operator<=>(const vector<Tree>& x, const vector<Tree>& y) {
  return std::lexicographical_compare_three_way(
    x.begin(), x.end(), y.begin(), y.end(), std::compare_three_way()
  );
}
```

the [`compare_three_way()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/compare/compare_three_way) contrains the `value_type` of `vector` which is `Tree` must satisfied the [`std::three_way_comparable_with`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/compare/three_way_comparable) concept, but we don't define any `operator<=>` for the `Tree`, so we get `Constraints not satisfied`.

Comment: Hmm, this explains why the current implementation of the standard library fails, but strictly speaking, this does not imply the program is ill-formed. It is not clear to me why `std::three_way_comparable_with` cannot work on `Tree` in some other stdlib implementation.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are not clear about?

Comment: I don't like the phrase "we don't define any operator<=> for the Tree, so we get Constraints not satisfied". `std::vector` contains `operator<=>` member, `Tree` inherits this member and thus should satisfy `std::three_way_comparable_with`.

Comment: `Tree` inherits `std::vector<Tree>` not `std::vector`, and the `operator<=>` of the `std::vector<Tree>` depend on the `operator<=>` of the `Tree`, if we don't have `operator<=>` for the `Tree`, we can not `three_way_comparable_with` `std::vector<Tree>` since it depends.